# Exception throws on TFS on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, tfs, team-explorer

I am using Windows 10 on my machine. i recently installed VS2010 + Service pack1 for VS but when I open the TFS window, the following screen with exception messages appears:

[image]

And when i click on the **"Connect to Team Foundation Server"** as below;
[image]

it gives me below error:

[image]

And there is no file with the name of **ActivityLog.xml** at the following link:

> C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

Can someone point out where is the mistake or how to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if it was working earlier then try clearing the cache from %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache

if it wasn't working earlier check if you have installed TFS 2010 SP1. Then clear the cache and try connecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to run [Devenv /log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272(v=vs.100).aspx) command to log all activity to the log file for troubleshooting.

Secondly, the error message you have indicates that there is something wrong with Team Explorer. So in order to fix this issue, you need to repair your VS2010 to have team explorer repaired to.